# Python DB-Connection via string

Tags: python, database-connection, pymysql

I'm searching the Internet for about an hour or so, but can't find a solution for my problem:

I'm trying to set up a Database connection. 
If I open the connection like this everything works fine:

```
db = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='python', db='test')
```

But if i want to set up the connection via string I get an error:

```
db_file = str("host='127.0.0.1', user='python', db='test'")
db = pymysql.connect(db_file)
```

Errormessage:

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on "host=\'127.0.0.1\', user=\'python\', db=\'test\'" ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)')
```

I hope anybody can help me out by telling me how to set up the database connection via string(or something else predefineable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a single string as parameter to the function pymysql.connect(), but it expects 3 parameters at least: host, user, db.

So the string db_file gets loaded as the first parameter (host), nothing gets in the other two, generating the error.

The correct way is something like this:

```
host = '127.0.0.1',
user ='python' 
db ='test'
db_conn = pymysql.connect(host, user, db)
```

UPDATE:

if you want to use a connection file directly try using Option Files:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-option-files.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. I try to adapt an older routine where I had an sqlite3 database-file (there the name db_file comes from) to simply writing all my stuff into a database server. I really don't want to rewrite all this old coding and replacing the parameters everywhere. Therefore I tried to set up the connection with one single parameter.

Comment: I suggest you to adapt your codebase to the new method, but if you want to pass a file i suggest you try using option files: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a string in for multiple arguments like that, you would have to assign each argument to it's own variable like this;

```
host = '127.0.0.1'
user = 'python'
db = 'test'
db_connect = pymysql.connect(host, user, db)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but that doesn't do the trick for me (see the comment I put under m.rp's answer.

Comment: Unfortunately you do have to define them individually, although once they're defined once you can reuse those variables across the whole code base.

Comment: I feared I had to swallow this bitter pill :/